# R Notebook ioslides ggplot/autoplot error

Tags: r, ioslides

I'm trying to create a presentation in R Notebook with ioslides...when I load libraries at the beginning of my code, they appear in the background of the slides. How can I prevent this from occurring? My slides appear as normal, but in the background is the library name and some additional R Console output...

````
---
title: 'sample preso'
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r libraries}
library(fpp2)
```
````

Comment: I haven't used ioslides in a while, but it seems like you're putting code into what's intended to be the title slide. Once you break it up with headers into multiple slides, the layout changes. Have you read the docs? https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/ioslides-presentation.html

Answer (score 0):

We can specify the `echo` as `FALSE`

````
```{r libraries, echo = FALSE}
library(fpp2)
```
````

Comment: I often use `{r libraries, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment=FALSE, results=FALSE}` in my .Rmd files (rather than `echo = FALSE`), so that might be worth a try if `echo = FALSE` doesn't fix the problem.